# How to properly implement equality of entities and value objects in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

1. Entities should not have equality comparison (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRCOKKUSp9s).
2. Value objects should have equality comparison (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRCOKKUSp9s)
3. Value objects can reference entities (Domain-Driven Design book)
4. Value objects are equal if all (or some?) of their attributes are equal (this one is not so explicitly stated, but it seems natural, https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html,http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/01/11/entity-vs-value-object-the-ultimate-list-of-differences/, https://projectlombok.org/features/Value). There might be rare exceptions (for example, (1, min) == (60, seconds)).

So if a value object has a reference to an entity, how should we include entity in that `equals()` comparison if we cannot call `equals()` on entity? Where is the flaw?

For me it is natural to implement `Entity.equals()` (usually based on type and ID). It is strange that I encountered that video (1).

Answer (score 1):

Value objects are equal if **all** of their attributes are equal. Now let's see how is it for value objects that refer to entities. Entities needs to have a unique identifier (id) and that id is allowing the value object to refer to the entity. In other words the value object will have an attribute which have the entity id (userID for example) and in the `vo.equal()` you just include that attribute.

I don't think there is any need to implement `Entity.equals()`. Entities are designed to be unique even if they have all the same attributes and that's why we use ID to differentiate them. There might be the need to ask "is these two VOs referring to the same entity?" (same example in first video second 0:33) but other than that I don't see any need to compare Entities.

Comment: I don't think it's usually a good design if different entities have all equal fields but differ only in ID, wich is generated by database (well, maybe there are some rare exceptions). I think they should usually have at least one unique set of fields (for example, person code, not only database generated person ID).

Comment: Syntax `entity1.equals(entity2)` is cleaner than `entity1.getId().equals(entity2.getId()) && entity1.getClass().equals(entity2.getClass())` even not mentioning missing null checks. Also `entity1.equals(entity2)` is cleaner than `Entities.equal(entity1, entity2)` or `Entities.equalIdsAndTypes(entity1, entity2)` (consider, for example, putting objects to a hash table).

Comment: Entities must have IDs but not necessarily database generated. If you will start ignoring that ID and compare entities field by field you will be missing the point of using entities and value objects.